# Laravel 5.2 Registration, Insert in multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I Want to create a custom registration form with many fields.

These fields will have to be inserted in different tables, and finally the user(Custom Model) table.

user table will have a reference to the new records that have been inserted in all the tables (like roles/organizations).

Can some one help me with the setup please. I'm 2 days old in the Laravel world :)

Comment: post what have you done so far

Comment: I've only created a new project and run the make:auth command so the registration and login links appear, 
I've created migrations for all the tables i have in the DB
so the tables are all created

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've not modified the User model according to the DB structure as yet.

Also my table Names start with Uppercase, So my users table in the DB is actually "Users", does that matter??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this.
1. The Laravel way, defining & utilising relationships. (they are awesome).
2. running multiple inserts on multiple tables with their respective models.
3. leaving eloquent aside, and insert using fluent query builder.

You may also want to wrap these insert queries into a transaction, if the need be.

Comment: Can you direct me to some such sample/tutorial?

Comment: Laravel's documentation covers Relationships in details, here is the link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks Rahul.. so after i define all these relations, how do i insert in all of the tables?? i'll have to write independent Create::'Model' statements for each model right??

Comment: you can do that, but you can save through relationships as well.. did you went through the entire page I shared? specially this part: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: I have to insert in Organization, Roles, Roles-Access, Users and User Details in that sequence.. 
I went through the entire documentation, and understand it conceptually, can you give  a sample code structure that may be used.
I know the Model definitions... That i am able to do.

Comment: There are different methods to save different type of relations. And Laravel docs have provided one example with every type of method available. Only you can figure out how they fit in your project, if I've to do it.. I need to know exact database structure you've built and type of relationship you have/want to built among those tables. But if you really wanna learn these things. I suggest you put in your efforts, and don't lose hope. Play try & error game.. and I think that is the best way to learn anything..

Answer (score 0):

please review bellow steps/code

**Route:** 
    ***route.php***

```
Route::get('member/create',['as'=>'member_create','uses'=>'MemberController@member_create']);
Route::post('member/create', ['as' => 'member_create_post', 'uses' => 'MemberController@member_create_post']);
```

**Controller:** 
    ***MemberController.php***

```
public function member_create(){
            $User=new User();

            return view('member.create');
        }


        public function member_create_post(U){
            $User=new User();
            $user_role=new UserRole();

            <<perform insert in users table as well in user role table >>

        }
```

**View:**
    ***resources/views/member/create.blade.php***

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo route('member_create_post'); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </form>
```